# Error generating text with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to generate a simple image with a caption at the bottom. The image is a transparent PNG with standard meme-text (white Impact with a black stroke border, centered at the bottom). This was working fine a little while ago, but I've since had to start fresh. I'm not on High Sierra and have a freshly installed version of homebrew and Imagemagick

`Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-33 Q16 x86_64 2018-05-18 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png rsvg tiff xml zlib`

When I run this command: `convert -size 600x200 xc:none -coalesce -font Impact -pointsize 50 -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -gravity south -annotate 0 "one two" caption.png`

I get this error: `convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition`path' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/4205.`

The same thing happens no matter what text drawing method I use. `-annotate`, `label:""`, `caption:""`. Only `-draw` gives me something different and it's the same except that instead of `path` it says `text` in the error.

After looking this up on other SO questions, I tried a simplified command, which worked. Sussing out the differences, I found that if I remove `-stroke black`, the command runs. Alternatively, if the text I attempt to draw has no spaces in it, the command also works.

As a bit of a confusing point, the command does actually produce the output I want. However, it also returns an exit code of 1, making it not useful in a script.

What could be going wrong and why does this not appear to work correctl anymore?

Comment: Why do you have `-coalesce`?

Comment: Out of interest V7 uses magick rather than convert - although convert is working as a legacy command. It is also more critical about the order of options etc.

Comment: It is a bug, since IM 7.0.7.29. Likewise in IM 6. I will report it. This is my command `magick -size 600x200 xc:none -font Impact -pointsize 50 -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -gravity south -annotate +0+0 "one two" caption.png`

Comment: See bug reports at: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34017 and http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34016 and http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34014

Comment: A message from the ImageMagick developer said this would be fixed in the next release, likely available sometime tomorrow.